# Truncate partitioned table - PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, partitioning

I have a master table called fact_sgw and have a child table called fact_sgw_2016_06 which is just data for June 2016. Could I truncate the child table without losing any data from the master table (fact_sgw)?

Comment: use `TRUNCATE ONLY childtablename` - see in docu - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-truncate.html

Comment: Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2):

`TRUNCATE TABLE <child_table_name>` works fine on Postgres 14.